# Regular Expression for filtering invalid windows characters in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regular expression which will allow me to check if the String has invalid (Windows) Characters.
Here is my sample code:-

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     String folderName = ">aa?|<";

     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".[\\\\/:\"*<>|].*$");
     Matcher m = p.matcher(folderName);

     if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Match");
     } else {
        System.out.println("Un-match");
        }
    }
}
```

The pattern works fine if the special characters are in between the alphabets ( like for ex. "a>a")

Can anyone please suggest the appropriate expression.
I have searched many links but couldn't get a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the rule here?

Comment: Check if the given string has characters that are not allowed by windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your initial dot is matching exactly one character. Change it to `.*` to match it zero or more characters.

So change `.[\\\\/:\"*<>|].*$` to `.*[\\\\/:\"*<>|].*$`.

Comment: If I do that, even if the string dosent contain any invalid characters it shows a match.

Comment: works for me.. `String folderName = "aaaa";Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*[\\\\/:\"*<>|].*$");` gives output as `Un-match`

Comment: Yeah it worked. Thanks a ton.
Instead of matches() method we can also use the find() method and keep the actual regex as [\\\\/:\"*<>|]. This will check if there is any special character present.